# Play an image sequence in the game-engine

Tags: animation, texturing, game-engine

I have baked animated shadows for an object as an image sequence. Now I need to be able to play the image sequence in the BGE, how do we do that ? 
I have found [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialsforblender3d.com/Blender_GameEngine/Animate-Texture/Texture_Animate_7.html) but you are supposed to make a sprite sheet, and I'm dealing with a large mesh that needs at least 1024px image for the shadow map.

Comment: If you have animated lightmap, than your pixel count is like that anyways. I don't see any way to make it consume less pixels:(

Comment: But isn't it a problem to have a 10240 * 10240 image in the game ?

Comment: Hm... And what's alternate? 100 frames of 1024 image? It is exactly the same. But you even can't use animated images in game, you can only scroll UVs, not change texture pixel color. Or maybe you could load each frame of texture during each frame? Making a huge use of RAM... I don't really think that what you're asking for is possible.

Comment: I'm dropping the idea for now, I'll use real time shadows as much as I can. thanks for your time.